# Problema al maquetar alturas en HTML con Bootstrap

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy realizando la maquetación de la estructura para páginas protegidas de una web.

En concreto, lo que quiero hacer es que la información se vea en toda la página (no haga scroll vertical ni horizontal) y dentro tener: una cabecera, un sidebar, el contendo y un pie de página.

En el caso de que desborde o bien el sidebar o el contenido, quiero meter unas barras de desplazamiento laterales para ver la parte que se queda fuera.

Para ello he creado la siguiente estructura:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body * {
  height: auto;
  max-height: inherit;
}

#cuerpo-pagina #sidebar,
#cuerpo-pagina #cuerpo-contenido {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Maquetado web</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid my-2">
    <!-- cabecera -->
    <nav class="navbar mb-2 navbar-dark bg-primary" id="cabecera">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Sidebar, cuerpo principal y cabecera -->
    <div class="my-2" id="cuerpo-pagina">
      <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-3 bg-secondary" id="sidebar">
          <ul style="list-style-type: square;">
            <li>Opcion número 1</li>
            <li>Opcion número 2</li>
            <li>Opcion número 3</li>
            <li>Opcion número 4</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="mr-1 col-8 bg-white" id="cuerpo-contenido">
          <!-- Contenido -->
          <div id="contenido">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quasi quas, beatae dolorum, reprehenderit necessitatibus ea iusto temporibus ab magni culpa veniam quae quo sed aliquam numquam at error recusandae soluta hic dicta mollitia eos dolorem. Accusantium,
            fugiat harum? Nam, delectus. Optio voluptatum ea quo! Quod ea enim sapiente impedit! Enim sed ad pariatur, culpa quaerat doloribus accusantium vel saepe illum repellendus. Perferendis ducimus, unde tempora odit illo quo natus modi, sapiente
            nam eveniet ut in necessitatibus placeat provident voluptas nihil, ullam ex eos velit temporibus? Excepturi totam suscipit sequi doloremque, modi in dolores repudiandae placeat? Voluptas officia ipsam praesentium, quibusdam quisquam rerum.
            Debitis, ullam! Aut deserunt tempora maiores, tempore quas suscipit iure odit quisquam quidem illum quod eligendi ullam sed, ea provident cumque officiis hic nesciunt! Unde autem maxime mollitia voluptatem a quod corporis, beatae, aliquam
            illum saepe dicta magnam necessitatibus reiciendis? Maiores quaerat cum natus dignissimos voluptas totam consectetur recusandae at fuga voluptatum repudiandae autem nulla nam, dolor quis? Aperiam dignissimos fugiat incidunt sapiente! Non maiores
            obcaecati impedit! Vitae nulla impedit ipsa eaque unde iure animi. Eum sit ex provident? Pariatur magnam enim harum ipsum, delectus voluptatum atque dicta nemo saepe vitae excepturi illo, possimus perspiciatis soluta placeat, veniam temporibus
            nihil natus aut rem distinctio hic magni. Nemo pariatur inventore eos voluptatum corrupti repudiandae labore voluptates magnam in! Fugit corporis ex nostrum, numquam ea est nihil molestiae ratione dolor? Voluptate ducimus vel officia voluptates,
            quaerat repellat debitis laboriosam doloremque libero beatae odio praesentium animi cum porro dolor quis alias iure natus unde! Atque voluptates ipsum, nesciunt sit praesentium repudiandae culpa! Explicabo modi placeat eveniet, temporibus
            illo pariatur magni. Ratione voluptates quisquam recusandae, excepturi molestiae corporis tempora fugiat architecto. Alias tenetur quod esse quo optio accusantium magni aliquam beatae sit harum cum, error nulla, et rerum nostrum atque quam
            nam laboriosam sint non voluptatum fugit! Ab excepturi in assumenda autem vero nemo, modi, labore tempora voluptatibus quae quos quaerat dignissimos id reprehenderit optio inventore animi earum, necessitatibus eius provident expedita nihil!
            Aperiam perspiciatis provident alias impedit nihil? Necessitatibus blanditiis, ea, harum molestiae voluptatibus cumque ipsum provident ullam neque laborum ratione consectetur odit atque ad qui perferendis officiis illum, libero vel? Quam illo
            dolorum explicabo aut temporibus quos quae porro inventore corrupti reiciendis corporis mollitia optio, deleniti, asperiores voluptas, atque laudantium nesciunt quis amet dignissimos soluta eveniet ea illum. Aut rem iusto quod commodi repudiandae
            molestiae nobis, eos totam atque dignissimos laborum necessitatibus iure facilis voluptate porro odio? Animi, amet. Libero provident deleniti excepturi ullam, asperiores ratione delectus ut iusto temporibus dicta accusantium sunt! Repudiandae
            cum tempora placeat inventore, molestiae harum culpa vel impedit. Quidem, aliquid. Autem necessitatibus atque culpa perspiciatis, ab quidem velit ipsa a vero excepturi neque, inventore delectus? Vero quis esse cum provident! Soluta dignissimos
            corrupti vero repellat cumque suscipit quos nam ullam hic fugiat sint, beatae nemo dolorem illo id esse, adipisci voluptatum, blanditiis corporis sit cupiditate! Necessitatibus maiores, consectetur vero saepe, quo nobis praesentium cupiditate
            provident quisquam corporis quos nulla? Perferendis non nostrum culpa sed? Fin de contenido
          </div>

          <!-- Pie de pagina -->
          <div id="pie">
            pie de p&aacute;gina
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Sin embargo, el resultado no es el esperado, ya que se me corta la información que sobresale de la página (sí que aparecen las barras laterales). En el caso que quite el overflow hidden del body tampoco funciona, ya que para ver la información de la página tendría que hacer scroll.

He estado mirando en w3cschools y vi que los valores de las propiedades height y width no se heredan por defecto salvo que se lo indiques. Llevo rompiendome la cabeza con esto varios días.

¿Me echais una mano? Muchas gracias.